# What statistical method to analyze relationship between ordinal and categorical variables?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, ordinal-data

I am working in my dissertation proposal and need to identify what is the best statistical method to analyze my research idea.

I am analyzing a company that sells gps services for vehicles. The service is sold on a year contract basis, so one of the main targets of the sales team is to get a high % of contract renewals every next year.

The company uses the Net Promoter Score index to evaluate the level of loyalty of the customers, classifying them as promoters, neutrals or detractors. I have the data of all customers NPS classification and also the historical information of the customers who renewed their contracts.

Is there a way to identify if there is a relationship between the NPS and the contract renewal performance?

Comment: Welcome to CV! I've edited your post to add the `ordinal` tag, since NPS is, from your description, an ordinal variable. I've also edited the title to better specify your question, but if I've erred in my interpretation please feel free to rollback the edit, or author a new title entirely.